# Adding function to differentiate between user and admin login page

Tags: php

Im currently working on this project for my assignment.i need to differentiate between user and admin on the login page. What changes should i made for the login page can differentiate between the user and admin ? these codes working just fine.

#### index.php

```
<?php 
require_once 'php_action/db_connect.php';
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
    header('location: http://localhost/managementsystem/dashboard.php');    
}

$errors = array();

if($_POST) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(empty($username) || empty($password)) {
        if($username == "") {
            $errors[] = "Username is required";
        }

        if($password == "") {
            $errors[] = "Password is required";
        }
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
        $result = $connect->query($sql);

        if($result->num_rows == 1) {
            $password = md5($password);
            // exists
            $mainSql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password='$password'";
            $mainResult = $connect->query($mainSql);

            if($mainResult->num_rows == 1) {
                $value = $mainResult->fetch_assoc();
                $user_id = $value['user_id'];

                //set session
                $_SESSION['userId'] = $user_id;

                header('location: http://localhost/managementsystem/dashboard.php');
            } else {
                $errors[] = "Incorrect Username or Password combination";
            }
        }else {
            $errors[] = "Username does not exists";
        }
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Log-in Page</title>
    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- bootstrap theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <!-- font awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- custom css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom/css/custom.css">    
    <!-- jquery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jquery ui -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <script src="assets/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!-- bootstrap js -->
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="container">
    <div class="row vertical">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-info">
                <div class= "panel-heading text-center">
                    <h3 class= "panel-title">MH ALLIM Management System</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <div class="messages">
                            <?php if($errors) {
                                foreach ($errors as $key => $value) {
                                    echo '<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></i>
                                    '.$value.'</div>';                                      
                                    }
                                } ?>
                        </div>

                    <form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST" id="loginForm">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputUser3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i>
                              Sign in</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </form>

                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

#### Session.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'db_connect.php';
//echo $_SESSION['userId'];

if(!$_SESSION['userId']) {
    header('location: http://localhost/managementsystem/index.php');
}
?>
```

should i modify the session so the normal user cannot access to the admin page ?
Thanks :)

Comment: When redirecting (after `header(...)`) also call `exit()` or `die()`. And it would be advised to generally not to display specific content to users, which shall not see it, for example, use if-else.

Answer (score 0):

You should have something that makes user and admin different. So, you can simply add a new column to your table with the name "role" (for example). If the user is a User, then the role will be "user". Same thing with any Admin, the role will be "admin".

And you can write the following code to your admin's page to prevent any login from unauthorized users. Use the same code with the user's page to prevent any login from any admin to the user's page "change this part to: $_SESSION['role'] != 'user')"

```
 <?php

    session_start();

    require_once 'db_connect.php';

    if( (empty($_SESSION['userId'])) || ($_SESSION['role'] != 'admin') ) {
        echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self');</script>";
    }
    else {
        $userId = $_SESSION['userId'];
    }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use if and else to separate it:

```
if(type="admin")
{
   do somethg
} 
else
{
   do somethg
}
```